# Persistir dados vindos do Storage Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, picasso

Bom galera eu comecei a trabalhar com o firebase storage, consegui enviar e receber os dados do firebase normalmente usando a documentação.

Porem gostaria que a foto que o usuário enviou e recebeu fosse mantida mesmo sem acesso a internet, alguém sabe como fazer isso ?

### Fragment que recebe a imagem

```
mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();


    //imagens instancia
    imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);

    btn_imagem = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

    btn_imagem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            i.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(i,GALERIA);

        }
    });

    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == GALERIA && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        progressDialog.setMax(100);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Upload de imagem");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Salvando...");
        progressDialog.show();
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        StorageReference filepatch = mStorageRef.child("Fotos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
        filepatch.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Uri imagemRecebida = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(imagemRecebida).fit().centerCrop().into(imageView);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Upload realizado com sucesso!!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vejo que você está utilizando Picasso para mostrar a imagem na tela. A biblioteca Picasso pode persistir a imagem no dispositivo, mas para fazer isso você terá de adicionar mais uma dependência (OkHttp) e mais algum código para configurar a ligação entre o Picasso e o OkHttp. Acho isso meio chato, e por isso prefiro utilizar a biblioteca [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). Esta biblioteca persiste a imagem por padrão, e não requer nenhuma configuração adicional. Substitua o Picasso por Glide, utilizando as dependências no gradle:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  google()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
}
```

E o seu método `onSucess()` ficará:

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    Uri imagemRecebida = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
    Glide.with(getActivity()).load(imagemRecebida).centerCrop().into(imageView);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Upload realizado com sucesso!!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```